# Eclipse support for burmese language?

Tags: android, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, southeast-asian-languages

I am designing an android application which also have burmese language support. But eclipse juno dosen't support burmese language, any idea how to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is create a separate language resource, **strings.xml**, which will contain all the Burmese translations for the texts you are displaying in the application. You should also have the English texts stored in strings.xml in a similar manner. Do not use hardcoded string anywhere for display.

Now, depending upon the user's language choice, you would display the strings using **`R.string.xxx`**.

NOTE : Make sure you have Eclipse file encoding as ***UTF-8*** not as the default *Cp1252*.

Comment: I am not sure if I was able to put forward the idea properly. Let me know if you need further clarification.

Comment: I know about the strings.xml but the question is that you can not paste or type burmese in that... it shows [][][][[] , which i think it means it dosen't support burmese font.

Comment: Did you change the eclipse encoding to UTF-8 ?

Comment: Is this problem only with Burmese or with other foreign languages as well? I mean, I have never worked with Burmese.

Comment: I had other languages which works fine, but I am sure there will be other minority languages too other than burmese which have this problem.

Comment: Yes, I can understand. Well, if you know the encoding format that supports Burmese, try checking if Eclipse has that or not.